# How can I set the timeout for my server-side action in Lightning?

Tags: apex, lightning

According to [the lightning documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm), I can call a server-side Apex method from lightning by using `$A.enqueueAction(action)`

I can set the callback for this action using `action.setCallback ()`.

Is there a way to set the timeout? We would like to extend it for a few seconds to increase the chances of it succeeding when Salesforce is undergoing high load.

I've trawled the docs and looked here for similar answers but no luck. Thanks!

**Edit:** we've used the Chrome debugger to inspect the action object returned by the `var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho")`, and we couldn't find a timeout value there.

Comment: You can't set the timeout for a specific action as the Aura framework bundles up multiple actions into a single XHR request - but you can set it globally: `$A.$clientService$.setXHRTimeout(10000);` but it's not officially supported - it will probably break at some point in the future(!), and not sure what happens with LockerService enabled. (https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/29fe973561ba9f851eca1a6f86b3f9ecbf777507/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/AuraClientService.js#L3732)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but a well-documented one :) If you post this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!